# Puedo eliminar registros con el mismo endpoint con el que estoy guardando en la BD mongo?

Tags: javascript, api, mongodb, post, get

la pregunta puede resultar confusa pero en si lo que estoy intentando hacer es que mi app guarde registros de un solo input que está dentro de un formulario, esto lo debe hacer si o si con el metodo get ya que debo enviar parametros (el valor del input) por la url que al final vendria siendo la url de las api que es la siguiente `http://localhost:3000/api?name=nombre+apellido`
hasta allí lo hace todo bien, el caso es que para la eliminación se debe usar la misma url solo que se le debe pasar el parametri kill debe quedar así `http://localhost:3000/api?kill=` ya que eso son los criterios que debo cumplir, el problema es que no tengo idea de como poder implementar eso.

lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
 <form action="http://localhost:3000/api">
      <input name="name" length="0" placeholder="Employee Name">
      <button type="submit" id="add">Add</button>
   </form>
   <br>
   <form action="http://localhost:3000/api" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="kill">
    <button>Kill All</button>
 </form>
```

y la api para guardar es esta:

```
router.get(``, async (req, res) => {
  const data = new Model({
    name: req.query.name,
  })
  //console.log(data.name);
  
   if (data.name !== undefined) {
    try {
      const dataToSave = await data.save();
      //res.status(200).send(dataToSave)
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'));
    }
    catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: error.message })
    }
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'));
  }
  
})
```

el codigo para eliminar que tengo y que funciona en postman es el siguiente:

```
router.delete('', async (req, res) => {
  const data = new Model({
    name: req.query.name,
  })
   try {
    //const id = req.query.id;
    // const data = await Model.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    const data = await Model.collection.drop()
    Model.collection.insertOne({
      "name": "Paul Herrick",
    })
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'));
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message })
  }

})
```

en conclusión lo que necesito es que la ruta de mi app funcione de la siguiente manera:
para guardar así: http://localhost:3000/api?name=nombre+apellido
y para eliminar así : http://localhost:3000/api?kill=

notese que solo cambia despues de la palabra api.

Comment: Si que se puede, en cuanto pueda publico una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Se lo agradezco mucho

Comment: y el parámetro kill que recibe? un id del que quieres eliminar? o eliminaría todos? Quizás sea un ejercicio, de lo contrario, es una muy mala práctica usar el metódo GET para eliminar registros de una BD

Comment: si, es solo para un ejercicio y el parametro kill no recibe nada, solo que cuando este en esa ruta debe ejecutarse algo que no tengo idea como implementar, debe eliminar todos los registros ya guardados

Comment: y que pasa si usan por ejemplo `http://localhost:3000/api?name=nombre+apellido&kill=`?

Comment: interesante, de momento solo se inserta en la base de datos (nombre apellido) pero me imagino que si ya estuviera programado el boton con el parametro kill eliminaria todo igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haría algo así:

```
router.get(``, async(req, res) => {
  //revisar si está el parametro name o está el parametro kill

  if (req.query.kill && req.query.name) {
    //Especificaron ambos parámetros... que hacer?
  } else if (req.query.kill) {
    //Código para eliminar los usuario
  } else if (req.query.name) {
    //Código para insertar el usuario
  } else {
    //No especificaron ninguno de los 2... que hacer?
  }
})
```

Comment: Tenias razon, era que yo lo estaba viendo de un enfoque diferente, gracias